# Laravel 6.8 PUT Method not working, Showing Blank Page

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Laravel 6.8 PUT Method not working for one of Controller, Showing Blank Page

Any suggestion or solution are most welcome. Following are summery of code.
Route Pointer is not going under Controller update function

**HTML edit.blad.php**  ( I tested with {{ method_field('PUT') }} )

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('certificate.update',$certificate_data->id) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

    // Other Form Fields 

</form>
```

**web.php ( Route File )**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::resource('certificate', 'CertificateController');
});
```

**php artisan route:list**
http://prntscr.com/qf662i

[this is output of route:list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keEPk.png)

**Controller Function**

```
public function update(Request $request, Certificate $certificate)
{
        echo 'vvvvv'; 
        return $certificate;
        return $input = $request->all();

}
```

**Pointer not coming into controller update and showing only blank page**
**I also tested with all function into the controller**

For reference -> If I change web.php and do following code then pointer is coming there. But not into Controller update function.

```
Route::put('certificate/{certificate}', function ($certificate) {
        return $certificate;
})->name('certificate_update');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your code everything looks good.

- You already tested PUT & PATCH variations as per expert suggestions here.
- You can get pointer into route file (web.php) but not into controller's Any function >>> That means pointer is not passing to controller.

**Reason for pointer not going into controller from route file**

- Your Path OR Name of controller is wrong / mismatched
- Controller file is called from another place

**Question**

- Any BACKUP FOLDER or BACKUP CONTROLLER files stored there into ??   [ \app\Http\Controllers\  ]

If answer is YES then it might be possible that wrong controller from backup is called from laravel cache. REMOVE Those backup files and Folders from controller folder.

**Solution**

I think controller PATH is cached and wrong controller is called instead. 
Try following commands to clear general cache.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
```

To clear controller file / path cache. We'll have to regenerate autoload.

Try following command. (**This step is important**)

```
composer dumpautoload
```

If this solves your issue then you can use normal html edit.blade form syntax as following.

```
<form action="{{ route('certificate.update',$certificate_data->id) }}" method="post">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
       {{ method_field('PUT') }}

       // Other form fields

</form>
```

On your controller. Your normal code should work like following.

```
public function update(Request $request, Certificate $certificate)
{
    return $certificate;
}
```

Let me know if this process helps you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Viral
I tried all possible suggestion given here. And yes you are correct. I have backup files there. I removed them and it start showing error of controller not found. That confirms wrong controller was calling. I removed them and [ composer dumpautoload ] command did trick for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `php artisan route:cache` is the trick! In some Laravel  apps I need to clear the route cache on every change,

Answer (score 4):

**controller**

```
public function update(Request $request,$certificate)
{
return $input = $request->all();
}
```

**blade file**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('certificate.update',[$certificate_data->id,$certificate]) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

    // Other Form Fields 

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas But that didnot helped. This returns to same blank page. I tested all functions into that controller and pointer is going to none of the functions. But if i change to web.php and try to catch PUT action then i can get pointer into route file

Comment: `<form action="{{ route('certificate.update',$certificate_data->id) }}" method="post">"`

Answer (score 0):

try change your function in controller like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $certificate)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but nope that did not worked. I already tested that way.
ie. http://prntscr.com/qf6fft

Answer (score 0):

Change your action to this

```
action="{{ route('certificate.update',[$certificate_data->id,\App\Certificate::find($certificate_data->id) ]) }}"
```

Or

```
action="{{ route('certificate.update',[$certificate_data->id,App\Certificate::find($certificate_data->id) ]) }}"
```

Instead of `PUT` use `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">`

Comment: Thanks Prashant for suggestion. 

That generated error --> http://prntscr.com/qf6ln6

So tried this solution --> http://prntscr.com/qf6mwl  and error solved. 
But then again on submit .. pointer is not going to update in controller

Comment: Thanks @Prashant but that generate error -> http://prntscr.com/qf6wg6

Even if i use static record ID then also it goes to blank page

Comment: That didnot give any error like before but again on submit it goes to blank page. 
I think edit.php page is fine as we can get pointer in web.php router page with put. But it not going to controller update method. This looks area of focus. 

Thanks Prashant for your all suggestions.

Comment: @VipulGhetiya Change PUT to PATCH

Comment: That suggestion give me error like this -> https://prnt.sc/qf7a08

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to the following artisan command first:
`php artisan cache:clear` to make sure cache is not the issue here.

Also could you try to put
`dd('test');` in the first line of your update function, to make sure no result is shown?

If it's not working can you show me your model? And controller?

All of the code you show looks good to me